# Using lodash ._template for emails

Tags: node.js, lodash

I'm trying to create an HTML email template with Node.js using lodash `_.template`. When I use the code below, I get this error: `((__t = ( firstName )) == null ? '' : __t) +`.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Also, should there just be one template that is compiled for all of the dynamic fields?

```
var firstName = _(contactinfo).pluck('firstName');
var compiledFirst = _.template('template with <%= firstName %>!');
var htmlFirst = compiledFirst(firstName);

var lastName = _(contactinfo).pluck('lastName');
var compiledLast = _.template('template with <%= lastName %>!');
var htmlLast = compiledLast(lastName);

var data = {
    from: store@example.com,
    to: email,
    subject: 'Your Order Confirmation',
    html: '<p>Dear '+ htmlFirst + htmlLast+': '</p><br>
<p>Thank you for your order. . . </p><table><tr>
<thead><th><strong>Items</strong></th></thead></tr></table>'
}
```

Here is what the array looks like:

```
[
    {
      "address": "555 Broadway",
      "city": "New York",
      "email": "johndoe@example.com",
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "phone": "2125551212",
      "state": {
        "code": "NY",
        "state": "New York"
      },
      "value1": true,
      "zip": "10001",
     "$id": "-K-qmfZzHgQaEM7uHKEK",
    }
  ]
```

Comment: You are doing `pluck('firstName')` for `lastName`

Comment: @Explosion Pills Thanks for point that out. Fixed it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [`pluck`](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck) returns an array with the `firstName` (or chosen attribute) for all objects in the array. Not only that, but you have to name the object in the template:

```
var firstName = _(contactinfo).pluck('firstName');
var compiledFirst = _.template('template with <%= firstName %>!');
var htmlFirst = compiledFirst({firstName: firstName[0]});
```

It would probably be easier to just have a single template and pass the `contactInfo` object to that:

```
var htmlAll = _.template('<%= firstName %> <%= lastName %>')(contactInfo[0])
```

Keep in mind that this only gets the 0th contactInfo entry. If you want more than one you will probably have to iterate -- you can also do that in the lodash template though.

Comment: Would I define firstName and lastName as I did in the first line if I'm going to use the `var htmlAll`?

Comment: @Ken for the second example you don't need to

Comment: OK. I tried that and defined `var contactinfo = req.body[0];` but then I got a `cannot read property '0' of undefined` error

Comment: @Ken okay that sounds like a separate problem.  Seems like `contactinfo` was never being populated.

Comment: You're right; fixed that problem. Your solution works great.

Comment: When you said I could iterate within the lodash template, did you mean use `forEach` within the template itself? And, in that case, should `(contactInfo[0])` become `(contactInfo)` in the answer above?